# Django restricting drag and drop based on database conditions

Tags: javascript, python, django

hopefully I can make this clear:
I have javascript code that allows for drag and drop functionailty of my website. I need the drop to only be allowed if certain objects from my database are not all ready on the div. To do this I would need to query the DB. But, apperantly we cannot query django DB using templating language, so I am not sure how to do this.

Specific use case: I have course objects and a prerequestie realation that shows which courses a prerequistie for other courses. I want to be able to drop the course on the planner only if all the courses prerequites are already on the planner. So I would need to query the courses prerequistes to see if any are in the planner already. would I need to use something like AJAX for this? When I first started with django I thought I would be able to use its template tags to do this but they dont seem to work well with querying or with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a reason Django does not like allowing you to querying the database in templates. Separation of logic code and UI code is very sound design.

What you need to do is to query the database *before* loading the template and then pass the data to the template in a variable. This way the template can build itself based on the data and can either allow or disallow drag and drops based on that (you can use jquery for dynamic allowing/disallowing, enable or disable elements based on form entries).

Edit (moved from comment)

You could alternatively create a REST API and query it with ajax, then restructure your webpage based on the result. Or you could create a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) within Django and use that to hit the database. You might have issues with the custom filter as Django templates are designed for server side generation and trying to dynamically update the site with them will likely be quite painful.

Comment: This would require me querying every single set of pre reqs for every single course, which would result in a lot of variables needing to be passed into the template. I would like to only make the query if the course is being dropped. Is this achievable with jquery? if so how would I connect jquery to the database? would I need some additional plugins?

Comment: hmm if you want to do it that way then you have 2 options. 1 create a REST API and use ajax to query it for database information, 2 design a custom filter in Django. I would tend to go with 1 as 2 is quite ugly in my opinion and feels quite hamfisted (ive done it several times and it chills me every time)

Comment: awesome, I will look up some tutorials to rest api and django, thank you!